# Looking to make a data sorting VBA script for excel. I have most of it written, but I'm stuck on one line

Tags: excel, vba

**EDIT: I've updated the question to be more specific as to what the issue is. After the code is posted, I go into detail about what's going wrong, and the advice I'm looking for.**

Thanks for all the help so far. I'll be more thorough in this post than I've been before.

[image: Sample Dataset]
The dataset I have looks like this. Columns A and B contain data for each person, represented by and ID number. C contains the numbers of "entries" available for them. There are four Headers for each entry. D to G are the cells I want to populate.

The rest of the rows contain the actual data we want to sort. Column H tell us whether or not there is data available. Column I contains the same ID number again (matches with row A). ID 505 has 8 entries (only 2 shown), each with four headers. What I want to do is write a script that will copy that will first, create 7 more rows for ID 505, and past the four headers of Entry 1 into the first, Entry 2 into the second, and so on. Where there is only 1 Entry, there is no need to make a new row. Because there are 400 IDs, and some with 36 entries, I'm trying to make this as automated as possible. A previous approach had me write a script with 1000s of lines, having each entry defined as a separate Dim, with statements like `If Entry7 <> "" and Entry 8 = "" Then` followed by the specific instructions for copying and pasting the 8 lines. This, however, would be a very long script.

What I have so far is as follows.

```
Sub EntrySort()


Dim i As Long, k As Long, N As Long, Entry As Range, Rng As Range


    i = 2
    While i <= 400
        Set Entry = Range("K" & i)
        For k = Columns("K").Column To Columns("GB").Column Step 5
            Set Entry = Union(Entry, Cells(i, k))
        Next k
        Set Rng = Range("D" & i)
        N = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Entry)  

        'count the number of entries for each ID'
        If Rng.Offset(, 4) = False Then
            i = i + 1 'skip IDs with no data'
        ElseIf N = 1 Then
            Rng.Offset(, 7).Resize(, 4).Copy
            Rng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            i = i + 2

        ElseIf N <> 1
            For X = 1 N
                Rng.Offset(, -3).Resize(, 670).Copy
                Rng.Offset(1, -3).Insert Shift:=xlDown 
                'This should create the number of rows required, based on the number of entries
            Next X
        Else
            Rng.Offset(, 7 + 5 * N).Resize(, 4).Copy
            Rng.Offset(N, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
            'after the new rows are made, this should copy the data from each entry and past it into its own row.'
            N = N - 1
        End If

        N = N - 1

    Wend
End Sub
```

Where the problem seems to lie is in `X to OriginalN... Next` statement. I want it to repeat the making of a new line N times, but when I execute this code, it seems to skip over that part. Is this the correct annotation? I've used OriginalN as an integer, since the original value for N (as the next few lines will start to decrease it). Is this the correct approach? It seems as if the script is skipping these two lines entirely and going straight to the copy/paste part.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For me it's not clear what your actual question is besides that you want us to write some code.

Comment: Apologies. I'll update to include what's actually going wrong with this code.

Comment: @user1996971 : When editing your post, use the space and formatting to make it more readable (preview right under edition box). Use 2 line returns to actually change line, use ** to mark **surrounded text in bold**, ...

Comment: Is there any particular part where the formatting is off?

Comment: Formatting: every block must be indented 4 spaces relative to the enclosing block. So at the end before `End Sub`, the `Wend` must be indented 4 spaces and before that the `End If` must be indented 8 spaces. Block indentations help giving the reader the overview of your program structure.

Answer (score 2):

The only explanation is that `ElseIf N = OriginalN Then` is never true, which means that in `N = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Entry)` the count never yields `N`. You can take the program into the debugger to check this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited out the OriginalN and went with a different approach. Still not working yet!